# Infinite While Loop Help Needed

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
print("Hi. Welcome on Guess The Number!!")
from random import randint
randomnumber = randint(1,100)
print("Guess the number!!")
usernumber = int(input("Which number am I thinking about?"))
try = 0
while usernumber != randomnumber:
    if usernumber < randomnumber:
        print("Lower...")
        print()
        try += 1
        usernumber = int(input("Which number am I thinking about"))
    elif usernumber < randomnumber:
        print("Higher")
        print()
        try += 1
        usernumber = int(input("which numberam I thinking about?"))
print("Finally!!!")
if try <= 10:
    print("Well done!!")
elif try > 10:
    print("U lost")
print()
print("The End!")
```

This causes me an infinite loop when I put an input number that is higher than the random number.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check your `elif` comparison and compare it with the `if`.

Comment: `try` is a keyword and shouldn't be used as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, both the `if` and the `else` only cater to `usernumber < randomnumber`. This is why you will end up with an infinite loop - because you haven't coded the `if-else` branch, that would handle such a case.